# File.Exists not working when application is run from NSIS installer

Tags: c#, nsis

I have written a simple firmware update utility that needs run as part of an installer. The installer installs the main application as well as the binary firmware files and the firmware update installer all into the install directory. In the update utility, I check for the existence of the file before trying to upload it to my device.

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists("My_Firmware.bin"))
  //handle error
```

This returns false and my utility fails out, but only when called directly from the NSIS installer. If I run the utility directly from the install directory by double clicking on the executable, it works fine. I'm using `ExecWait` to run the utility.

```
ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\UpdateUI.exe"'
IfErrors 0 noError
messageBox MB_OK "No firmware was installed!"
```

I've tried running the installer as administrator. I've also tried changing the install directory to somewhere less likely to have permissions issues. I tried using just `Exec` whith the same result. I also tried just removing the `File.Exists` check to see if the file would open anyway, which it did not.

Comment: You are using a relative path. Such paths are always relative to the `working directory`.Are you sure the `working directory` is the same in both cases? Please note, the `working directory` is not always the same as where your program is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSIS isn't setting the current, working directory to that folder, which is causing your executable to fail.

One option would be to pass in the full path on the command line:

```
ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\YourProgram.exe" "$INSTDIR\My_Firmware.bin"'
```

This would allow you to have your program read from the command line arguments, and use the file (with full path) instead of hard coding it to the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the working directory in NSIS with `SetOutPath`.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing and it fixed the problem. `setOutPath $INSTDIR`